# Can I keep my chat with darkness in it?

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, chat

I prefer a dark color-scheme for almost all my activities online, including the 2nd monitor.

For SE chats I have a special extension installed, that inverts colors and has some other gimmicks. Unfortunately since the design update I can hardly write chat messages, because I can't really read them...

[image]

It seems that's because the background color of the `#input`-rule is marked `!important` (thanks to @Kitler for finding)

Can this rule please be not marked important as to allow simplistic dark-theming?

Comment: For the record, PorkChat seems to work fine with the new design: http://i.imgur.com/lFrYBEX.png

Comment: As the extension you have is not an official one by Stack Exchange, what do you expect really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't really want to change our code only to accomodate random extensions that someone may have installed. I'm sure that your extension has ways to handle this.